# How to run an Rscript with entrypoint when using docker?

Tags: r, docker

I'm trying to run an Rscript through entrypoint but for some reason when I do this it fails to recognize the file. Here is an example.

```
docker run -it --rm  -v /N/Rfinal/:/tmp --entrypoint "Rscript /tmp/test.R" rocker/rstudio:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: 
starting container process caused "exec: \"Rscript /tmp/test.R\": 
stat Rscript /tmp/test.R: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

The way I can get bash command is through entrypoint for this particular docker. Is there anything I can do? thanks.

Comment: Make the entrypoint “Rscript” and then put the file name after the docker image name. The entry point is the executable, not the full command

Comment: `docker run --entrypoint` is a little inconvenient, and most images don't actually need it.  Can you `docker run ... rocker/rstudio Rscript /tmp/test.R`, providing a command override (without quotes around it) instead of trying to override the entrypoint?

Comment: @jakub thanks that makes so much sense now that you put it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--entrypoint` argument takes the name of the executable, like `bash`, `Rscript`, `python`, etc. The arguments to that executable would go after the docker image name.

```
docker run -it --rm  -v /N/Rfinal/:/tmp --entrypoint Rscript rocker/rstudio:latest /tmp/test.R
```

You would use the form to override the default entrypoint of the docker image. But the rocker docker image does not set an entrypoint, so the entrypoint is `/bin/sh` (found after tracing the base image to `ubuntu:focal`). Because the entrypoint is `/bin/sh`, you can simply use `Rscript /tmp/test.R` after the docker image.

```
docker run -it --rm  -v /N/Rfinal/:/tmp rocker/rstudio:latest Rscript /tmp/test.R
```

Comment: *But the rocker docker image does not set an entrypoint, so the entrypoint is `/bin/sh` (found after tracing the base image to `ubuntu:focal`) - how did you find this? I clicked on 'focal' [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu), and it took me to [here](https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+oci/ubuntu-base/plain/Dockerfile?h=refs/tags/dist-focal-amd64-20221019&id=7f6cfb71524baae0a1019f2c7b2530dff2d40c6e) which appears to show bash as the entry point, rather than `/bin/sh` ?